# C saving files as `'filename'$'\n'` with `fopen(filename, "w")`

Tags: c

I haven't programmed in C in a little while but I've never seen this behaviour before. It seems that when I open a file using `fopen(filename, "w");` the file for some reason is saved as `'filename'$'\n'`. For example, if filename stores "c.txt", once the program runs, `ls` displays `'c.txt'$'\n'`.

I am using fgets to retrieve user input but I have verified that the input in filename is correct with print statements.

I haven't been able to find any search results on this either but I tried writing a simple Python program to create a file and it does so no problem.

Does anyone know where this odd behaviour comes from?

Comment: It probably means you read the file name with `fgets()` or `getline()` and forgot to remove the trailing newline.  Use: `filename[strcspn(filename, "\n\r")] = '\0';` to safely zap the newline if it is present, and overwrite the null with null if it isn't.  The `\r` accommodates Windows line endings if they show up.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler! That did the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>*Transferring [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60979194/c-saving-files-as-filename-n-with-fopenfilename-w/60979777#comment107883759_60979194) into an answer.*</sup>

It probably means you read the file name with [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) or POSIX [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) and forgot to remove the trailing newline.

Use:

```
filename[strcspn(filename, "\n\r")] = '\0';
```

This safely zaps the newline if it is present, and overwrites the null with null if it isn't. The `\r` accommodates Windows line endings if they show up (they don't usually, but it might be relevant to you).